# ES6 add to module import a version hash

Tags: javascript, gulp, es6-modules

i have some issue with gulp and es6 module import, i need add hash to my import for better version control and add a prefix from this:

`import { someVar } from "./someFile.js";`

to this:

`import { someVar } from "./someFile.js?v=1.0.0";`

Is there any way to automate it with gulp?
Or meaby some other solution could work.
For now im changing the name of the folder to prevent cacheing.
best if it works with dynamic import's too